# How to modify a variable naming convention for pylint in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, pylintrc

I keep getting `C0103` warnings from pylint in Visual Studio, because I am trying to use 2-character variables names like `hp` and `gp`. The warning is described here: [link](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:c0103).

The convention is described as `[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$` for `variable-rgx`. I don't actually know how to read this regex thing or what it means, but it looks like the `{2,30}` part describes the possible length range, so (correct me if I'm wrong) why isn't character length two allowed? Or would there be some other reason why a variable name such as `gp` would give an error?

When this question is asked, people often link to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but I don't remember reading that variable names specifically must have a minimum length of 3 characters. Anyway, I get this is probably bad form, but I don't want to follow this convention. In the context of my program it is abundantly clear what 2-character variable names such as `gp` and `hp` would mean, and this feels like way to much of a restriction on coding style.

So in any case, what I want to do is specifically override this warning. I don't want to just disable `C0103`. I would instead prefer to change this within my text editor (Visual Studio Code), like in the setting where for example you can change `pylint` args with `"python.linting.pylintArgs": [...]`. So what would the correct change be if I wanted to override the convention to allow 2-character variable names? Or would I have to write a new lintrc file (not sure how to do that, and I would prefer a lighter solution where I only change it in VSCode).

Comment: You are correct that The {2,30} means at least 2 and no more than 30 characters but it only modifies the last [a-z0-9_] part of the regex.  So you need one a-z character followed by at least two other characters, which can now include numbers.  So can you just the 2 to a 1?  I don't have pylint installed so I don't know its linting args.

Comment: Ok I see how it works, thanks. The problem is I don't know how to (and where) to change the 1 to a 2. It would be useful if I could somehow override it from the VSCode settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open user settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>), input in the search bar `pylintArgs`, hover the mouse over the `"python.linting.pylintArgs": []` and select `edit`. It will be copied to either `User Settings` or `Workspace Settings` on the right side. There input the required parameter:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--variable-rgx=[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{1,30}$"
]
```